# Parsing multi-dimensional JSON array of Umbraco Nodes in JQuery

Tags: jquery, json, umbraco

Hoping someone can help - I'm not getting anywhere with this.
I've created a serialized JSON string consisting of some Umbraco nodes and I'm trying to get the values of certain properties using JQuery.

The attached image is the structure of the array, inspected using Chrome dev tools:
[image]

As you can see there are 3 arrays within the object and within each array there are 12 objects with 3 properties.
The array is structured in this way because I'm using getJSON() method.

Try as I have, I can't seem to access the properties in this.

I've stripped everything out of the JQuery, leaving the bare bones:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.getJSON('http://myURLCaseStudyImagesJSON', function (data) {

                });
            });
        </script>
```

If anyone can give suggestions as to how to do this I'd be very grateful.
I don't want to end up with loads of nested for loops, but even trying that doesn't give the results.
The actual raw JSON is like so:

```
[[{"Alias":"googleAC","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaKeywords","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaDescription","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageTitle","Value":"Royal","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageHeading","Value":"Royal Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageSubHeading","Value":"Royal Sub Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageContent","Value":"\u003cp\u003eRoyal\u003c/p\u003e","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caption","Value":"Dave didn\u0027t wait to book. We didn\u0027t wait to blink.","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyMainImage","Value":"1357","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyImages","Value":"1357","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"displayHomePageCarousel","Value":"1","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"imageUrl","Value":"/media/8777/swimmer.jpg","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyUrl","Value":"/our-work/advertising-and-promotions/royal/","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],[{"Alias":"googleAC","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaKeywords","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaDescription","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageTitle","Value":"Walter Title","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageHeading","Value":"Walter Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageSubHeading","Value":"Walter Sub Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageContent","Value":"\u003cp\u003eWalter Content\u003c/p\u003e","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caption","Value":"Mickey waved his magic wand and magic happened","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyMainImage","Value":"1355","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyImages","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"displayHomePageCarousel","Value":"1","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"imageUrl","Value":"/media/8767/mickey.jpg","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyUrl","Value":"/our-work/brandingcorporate-identity/walter/","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}],[{"Alias":"googleAC","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaKeywords","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"metaDescription","Value":"","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageTitle","Value":"Sea Life","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageHeading","Value":"Sea Life Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageSubHeading","Value":"Sea Life Sub Heading","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"pageContent","Value":"\u003cp\u003eSea Life Content\u003c/p\u003e","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caption","Value":"Sea life it\u0027s an education","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyMainImage","Value":"1356","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyImages","Value":"1356","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"displayHomePageCarousel","Value":"1","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"imageUrl","Value":"/media/8772/shark.jpg","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"},{"Alias":"caseStudyUrl","Value":"/our-work/print-designproduction/sea-life/","Version":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"}]]
```

Hope someone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What are you using to serialize the Umbraco objects to JSON?  In JSON.net you can create serializers that could reformat the data to make each of the 13 objects actual key/value pairs so they would have properties like you expect.

Here are some links on the JsonSerializer:

http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization

[How to implement custom JsonConverter in JSON.NET to deserialize a List of base class objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8030538/how-to-implement-custom-jsonconverter-in-json-net-to-deserialize-a-list-of-base)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by having nested $.each loops, which I didn't really want - but I read a forum post which said you can't really have multi-dimensional jQuery arrays and this would be the best way to do it.